# Extract onclick location.href from jquery object as a string

Tags: jquery, string, onclick

I'm trying to hijack a `button` element so I can open it's link in a new window. I've added a new attribute the elements which need to open in a new window called `data-ext-link="true"`. In some cases the `button` element has a `onclick` which contains the `location.href` that I need to send the user to. How can I grab that `location.href` using jquery so I can supply it to the `window.open` in my function?

The function below works great for anchor elements, but it's within my `is('button')` `if` statement where it gets hairy and doesn't work because `attr()` returns an object and not a string. The object It returns is the following:

## My Button Code:

```
<button data-ext-link="true" onclick="location.href='http://website/url_i_want'" class="btn2">Open it up</button>
```

## $.attr('onclick') Response:

```
function onclick(event) {
    location.href = "http://website.com/url_i_want";
}
```

## My Function:

```
function extLinks() {
    var extLinks = $('a[data-ext-link="true"], button[data-ext-link="true"]');

    $.each(extLinks, function(){
        if($(this).is('button')){
            var link = $(this).attr('onclick'); // Here it needs to be a string.
            link = link.match(/location.href='(.*)'/); //Won't work because it's an object.
            link = link[1];
        } else {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
        }
        $(this).unbind('click.extLink').bind('click.extLink',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.open(link);
        });
    });
}
```

## UPDATE:

I found the following related question which suggest using `$.live` which being deprecated I'd use `$.delagate()` instead, but this doesn't fully address the issue where I need to tell this button to open in a new window using it's `location.href` value inside the `onclick` as the target.

## SOLUTION:

```
function extLinks() {
    var extLinks = $('a[data-ext-link="true"], button[data-ext-link="true"]');

    $.each(extLinks, function(){
        if($(this).is('button')){
            var link = this.onclick.toString().match(/location\.href\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]*)['"]/)[1];
        } else {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
        }
        $(this).unbind('click.extLink').bind('click.extLink',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.open(link);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: There must be something else going on here.  Can you post the HTML code for a button where this method doesn't work?  Also, you may need to revise your regular expression - it won't work for the example you gave.

Comment: @jnylen: I've added further detail to my question.

Comment: I've confirmed that my solution works for me.  See http://nylen.tv/test-onclick.html.  Also, if you control the HTML for the whole page, it would be much, much easier to restructure the code not to require this kind of gymnastics (for example, use a dictionary of URLs, or put the URL in a `data-url` attribute of the button or link element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert the function to a string:

```
var link = $(this).attr('onclick').toString();
```

Note - I don't know if this will work in all browsers.  Works for me in Firefox and IE7 though.

---

Also, you may need to revise your regular expression - it won't work for the example you posted.  Try this:

```
/location\.href\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]*)['"]/
```

---

I've confirmed that this solution does work for me.  Here's an example page:  http://nylen.tv/test-onclick.html

Comment: I think that it's still returning an object even with the toString() appended.

Comment: Wouldn't it be somewhat easier to avoid creating a jQuery object, and just use `this.onclick.toString()`? And, incidentally, a JS Fiddle demo that confirms that the end result is a string: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WKycw/

Comment: Yes, `this.onclick` will work, but jQuery will use the "W3C preferred" way to get the attribute.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but your solution (removing the 'typeof') returns the same exact thing. `function onclick(event) { console.log(this); }`